Rust empty stdout of command
I'm using Command to spawn git diff {HASH} --unified=100000 --no-color --patch-with-raw --exit-code -- {FILE}. But I'm getting empty stdout and stderr. I've tried many ways of getting stdout (cli.wait(), cli.stdout.take()) but it also didn't work as expected.
pub fn get_commit_file_changes(hash: &str, file: &str) -> Option<String> {
    let file_path = format!("\"./{}\"", file);

    let mut cli = std::process::Command::new("git")
        .args([
            "diff",
            hash,
            "--unified=100000", // to get the whole file
            "--no-color",
            "--patch-with-raw",
            "--exit-code",
            "--", // to separate paths from revisions
            &file_path,
        ])
        .stdout(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to spawn cmd process");

    let output = cli
        .wait_with_output()
        .expect("failed to wait for child process");

    if !output.status.success() {
        return None;
    }

    let stdout = String::from_utf8(output.stdout).unwrap();
    let stderr = String::from_utf8(output.stderr).unwrap();

    if !stderr.is_empty() {
        return None;
    }

    if stdout.is_empty() {
        return None;
    }

    return Some(stdout.split("\n").skip(4).collect::<Vec<&str>>().join("\n"));
}

I've tried spawning shell (os specific) and then executing the git command, but it also didn't work.
#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
const SHELL: &str = "cmd";

#[cfg(not(target_os = "windows"))]
const SHELL: &str = "sh";

#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
const SHELL_FLAG: &str = "/C";

#[cfg(not(target_os = "windows"))]
const SHELL_FLAG: &str = "-c";

let mut cli = std::process::Command::new(SHELL)
    .args([
        SHELL_FLAG,
        "git",
        "diff",
// ...

Desired output
C:\Users\dallen\Desktop\gitty>git diff 76a9cea6bcdfc716a769e75001dadb770023a27f --unified=100000 --no-color --patch-with-raw --exit-code -- "./src-tauri/src/git/commit/mod.rs"
:100644 100644 309edda 0000000 M        src-tauri/src/git/commit/mod.rs

diff --git a/src-tauri/src/git/commit/mod.rs b/src-tauri/src/git/commit/mod.rs
index 309edda..ba536fc 100644
--- a/src-tauri/src/git/commit/mod.rs
+++ b/src-tauri/src/git/commit/mod.rs
@@ -1,286 +1,331 @@
-use std::io::Read;
+use std::{
+    io::{BufRead, BufReader, Read},
+    process::Output,
+};

 use serde::Serialize;

-use crate::utils::subprocess::create_git_cli;
+use crate::utils::subprocess::{create_git_cli, read_to_string};

 #[derive(Serialize)]
 pub struct Commit {
     pub hash: String,
     pub author: String,
     pub timestamp: u64,
     pub message: String,
     pub description: Option<String>,
 }
...


What's the output of your command when you run it on the terminal?

When I replace git with echo I do some output getting captured by your function so it does work.

@cafce25 ive updated question with desired output. it's a git diff output, but for some reason i dont get any of it in stdout

You should paste the output here, try print it out with println!("output {:#?}", output);

The issue is mainly due to you placing extraneous "'s around the file path.
If you executed the command in a shell, the "'s are used by the shell, foo is passed to git, and you would get output:
$ git diff -- "foo"
diff --git a/foo b/foo
index e69de29..5716ca5 100644
--- a/foo
+++ b/foo
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+bar

If you execute Command::new("git").args(["--", r#""foo""#]) in Rust, Rust passes "foo" to git, resulting in the equivalent of this:
$ git diff -- \"foo\"

Because there is no file named "foo", there is no diff for git diff to output.
By trusting Rust to pass the path properly, and by removing --exit-code to ensure a successful exit code despite the existence of a diff, we arrive at working code:
pub fn get_commit_file_changes(hash: &str, file_path: &str) -> Option<String> {
    let mut cli = std::process::Command::new("git")
        .args([
            "diff",
            hash,
            "--unified=100000", // to get the whole file
            "--no-color",
            "--patch-with-raw",
            "--", // to separate paths from revisions
            file_path,
        ])
        .stdout(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to spawn cmd process");

    let output = cli
        .wait_with_output()
        .expect("failed to wait for child process");

    if !output.status.success() {
        return None;
    }

    let stdout = String::from_utf8(output.stdout).unwrap();
    let stderr = String::from_utf8(output.stderr).unwrap();

    if !stderr.is_empty() {
        return None;
    }

    if stdout.is_empty() {
        return None;
    }

    return Some(stdout.split("\n").skip(4).collect::<Vec<&str>>().join("\n"));
}


unfortunately provided code doesn't solve a problem and output is still a empty string

The code worked for me on Linux, git version 2.25.1. Unfortunately, I can't help unless I can reproduce the problem.
